# Upload a sql database to Azure

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, azure-sql-server

Sorry about the newb question I'm new to Azure.

I've created a new (free) 20mb database in the azure portal which is fine. I'm trying to upload my website database using the 'Export to Azure' sql management studio function. However, instead syncing the DB over to the one I created in the portal it creates a new database. The new DB seems to support a minimum size of 100mb which is way to big for my requirements.

I would be grateful for any advise regarding the best way to proceed. I'm migrating the website in question to Azure, the database is quite small and basically I just need to copy it over and connect to it.

Thanks in advance.
William

Comment: Just use the SQL Azure Migration Wizard: http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/ it is the ultimate tool for migrating SQL Database to Azure SQL Database. And is developed by Microsoft's very own Database team.

Comment: You can always rescale the new DB to use less than 100 Mb afterwards

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool to migrate data **Microsoft data migrate assistant**

You can download from here. it's very easy to use

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595

there are some migrate mode you can use: ex from Sql to azure Sql like picture bellow
When migrate you can choose migrate schema and data and data only

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a great tool in Visual Studio Community Edition (free) for comparing both schema and data between two databases on different servers. It can then update the target database with any changes after which you can switch over to use the Azure DB.